# Javascript row number using for loop?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me with this Javascript problem? The code I've write is not quite right.

```js
function tes() {
  var c = document.getElementById('Text');
  var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  var txt = '';
  for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= a; j++) {
      if (j == i) {
        txt += i.toString();
      } else {
        txt += i.toString();
      }
    }
    txt += '<br/>';
  }
  c.innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<input id="a">
<button onclick="tes()">Input</button>
<div id="Text"></div>
```

[Javasript Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikjVz.png)

Expected output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 2 2 
1 1 3 3 3 
1 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: What is your *expected* output?

Comment: Can you post all of your code? Either that are you are just not setting the textContent of `a` to `txt`

Comment: @Nick its on the picture 'Javasript Problem'

Answer (score 1):

Since your problem required an input, you would be running the code when input is received. The only thing you got incorrect was really the if statement logic. `rowAmm` is a variable holding for the amount of `1s` in a row, if `j` was less than that, add another 1, otherwise add `i` which was the row number.

You won't have to do a `.toString()` function either if you're adding it to a variable which is already declared a string `var txt = ''`. Just like `5 + "5"` will become `55` while `5 + 5` will be `10`

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var textBox = document.getElementById("Text");
function makeSquare() {
  var b = a.value;
  var txt = '';
  for (i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
    var rowAmm = b - i;
    for (j = 1; j <= b; j++) {
      if (j <= rowAmm) {
        txt += "1";
      } else {
        txt += i;
      }
    }
    txt += '<br/>';
  }
  textBox.innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<input id="a">
<button onclick="makeSquare()">Input</button>
<div id="Text"></div>
```